# I'm getting an error that states "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer wit hout a cast [enabled by default]"

Tags: c, arrays, function

I need a little help with the error, not sure how to get around it.I am new to programming and I'm using Sublime Text editor and Cygwin64. This worked in the lecture that my teacher gave us, now i'm wondering if I have my compiler set up correctly?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 15


//@todo: function that will return avg of values in array
float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size);
//@todo: function that will return sum of values in array
int GetArraySum(int a[], int size);
//@todo: declare another function, one that multiplies all values by two

void DisplayArray(int a[], int size);
int GenerateRandomNumber(int UpperBound);

int main (void) {

    //seed the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    //declare an array
    int array1[SIZE] = {0};


    //populate the array
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = GenerateRandomNumber(i + 1);    
    }

    DisplayArray(array1, SIZE);
    printf("Array avg is: %f\n", GetArrayAverage(array1, SIZE) );
    printf("Array sum is: %d\n", GetArraySum(array1, SIZE) );

} // End Main Function

/* Custom Functions */
int GetArraySum(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;
    int Total = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Total += a{i};
    }
    return Total;
}
float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;
    int Total = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        Total += a{i};
}
return (float)Total / size;


void DisplayArray(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("Element: %d - Value: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}

int GenerateRandomNumber(int UpperBound){
    return (rand() % UpperBound);
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error point to?

Comment: There are quite a few syntax errors in the code. This could not have possibly "worked in the lecture". What is `a{i}` that you use in several places? Also, curly braces in `GetArrayAverage` are not balanced. That `a{i}` can probably cause the "warning" you reported... In any case, why aren't you telling us which line caused the warning? How are we supposed to figure that out?

Comment: Thank you, I missed the curly braces, they should have been brackets. Now I am getting another error that states..

Comment: InClass6.c: In function ‘GetArrayAverage’:
InClass6.c:76:2: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
  }
  ^

Comment: The error is from the last line on the code at the last curly brace.

Comment: @Michael E.: As I said, curly braces in `GetArrayAverage` are not balanced. Did you fix that? In any case, if you make changes to your code, you have to transfer them here as well. We are not clairvoyant or telepathic, we can't see what you are doing from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many syntax errors in your code, here is a working version, please compare against your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 15


//@todo: function that will return avg of values in array
float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size);
//@todo: function that will return sum of values in array
int GetArraySum(int a[], int size);
//@todo: declare another function, one that multiplies all values by two

void DisplayArray(int a[], int size);
int GenerateRandomNumber(int UpperBound);

int main (void) {

    //seed the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    //declare an array
    int array1[SIZE] = {0};


    //populate the array
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = GenerateRandomNumber(i + 1);    
    }

    DisplayArray(array1, SIZE);
    printf("Array avg is: %f\n", GetArrayAverage(array1, SIZE) );
    printf("Array sum is: %d\n", GetArraySum(array1, SIZE) );

} // End Main Function

/* Custom Functions */
int GetArraySum(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;
    int Total = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Total += a[i];
    }
    return Total;
}
float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;
    int Total = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Total += a[i];
    }
    return (float)Total / size;
}

void DisplayArray(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Element: %d - Value: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}

int GenerateRandomNumber(int UpperBound)
{
    return (rand() % UpperBound);
}
```

Comment: Sobibor, I was able to compile and run the repaired code, not sure how the last error was fixed though?

Comment: Sobibor, Thank you, I found my missing curly brace!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Total += a{i};// Wrong 
Total += a[i]; Array objects are accessed by array-name followed by [index number]
```

For srand include the `stdlib.h` header file and for time include the `time.h` header file.

In function `float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size)` put closing curly braces after the return statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 15


//@todo: function that will return avg of values in array
float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size);
//@todo: function that will return sum of values in array
int GetArraySum(int a[], int size);
//@todo: declare another function, one that multiplies all values by two

void DisplayArray(int a[], int size);
int GenerateRandomNumber(int UpperBound);

int main (void) {

     //seed the random number generator
     srand(time(NULL));

     //declare an array
     int array1[SIZE] = {0};


      //populate the array
      size_t i;

      for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
          array1[i] = GenerateRandomNumber(i + 1);    
      }

      DisplayArray(array1, SIZE);
      printf("Array avg is: %f\n", GetArrayAverage(array1, SIZE) );
      printf("Array sum is: %d\n", GetArraySum(array1, SIZE) );

 } // End Main Function

 /* Custom Functions */
 int GetArraySum(int a[], int size)
 {
     size_t i;
     int Total = 0;

     for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         Total += a[i];
     }
     return Total;
 }

 float GetArrayAverage(int a[], int size)
 {
     size_t i;
     int Total = 0;

     for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        Total += a[i];
      }
     return (float)Total / size;
 }

void DisplayArray(int a[], int size)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("Element: %d - Value: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}

int GenerateRandomNumber(int UpperBound){
    return (rand() % UpperBound);
}
```